# Recibir un unico objeto de una clase mediante JSON y parseo a java con GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

tengo un webService en PHP y MySQL que me envía correctamente un JSON con los datos que necesito. El problema lo tengo en que en la activity de android siempre he usado este código para parsear el JSON:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
p = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<List<Persona>>(){}.getType());
```

Y eso es muy útil cuando el JSON contiene varios objetos del la clase, en este caso Persona, pero yo recibiré siempre un único objeto de la clase Persona, por tanto utilizo este código:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
p = gson.fromJson(result, new TypeToken<Persona>(){}.getType());
```

y me da el siguiente error:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

PD: si utilizo a primera formula me da el error:

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de manejar los JSON con GSON?
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que recibes es solo un objeto (en lugar de un array de objetos) entonces para decodificar el json sería:

```
Persona persona = gson.fromJson(result, Persona.class);
```

*Nota: ojo que un array de un solo objeto sigue siendo un array.*